# Mic loopback but to different output device

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

i have a GE75 Raider 9SE with Ubuntu 22.04 and an Xbox Series X connected to a monitor.
This monitor has jack output, my MSI notebook has a mic input and a connected headset (with mic).

I want to have the monitor output into my microphone input and hear the audio on the headset while still using the microphone from the headset (I use it to talk on discord).

I've tried mic loopback but this streams to the notebook speakers and not to the headset, i confirm that this is working as i can hear my xbox sounds from the speakers.

I think this is because they are different audio cards. Am i wrong?

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Easily solved that by using alsaloop.

For anyone having this problem use aplay -l and arecord -l to list out and in devices, in my case i want to out primary mic to usb headphones, the command was that:

alsaloop -C hw:0,0,0 -P hw:2,0,0

Working perfectly!